DJI Payload-SDK Control yaw independently while in a Waypoint Mission
We are supplying a mission via the DJI Pilot 2 App and require the drone to be facing into the wind, or more accurately have a minimal roll component. To do this we want to yaw the aircraft to cancel out as much of the roll component as possible while effectively completing the mission.
We are looking at the examples given in the sample_c folder and have come across the DjiTest_FlightControlVelocityAndYawRateCtrl. However this looks like it may override the mission due to the following line, which requires x, y & z offsets in addition to yaw so implies that it may override the mission input.
T_DjiFlightControllerJoystickCommand joystickCommand = {offsetDesired.x, offsetDesired.y,offsetDesired.z,yawRate};

Our other line of though was to set the drone to point towards a point of interest and then edit the location of the PoI via the SDK; but we haven't found a method to edit the PoI.
We want to avoid creating a custom mission controller etc as we are hoping to leverage other 3rd party software which may be incompatible.

i'm relatively new to PSDK development, so please take this with a grain of salt.
the closest you can get to this is by modifying the E_DJIWaypointV2HeadingMode headingMode to DJI_WAYPOINT_V2_HEADING_MANUAL (in the T_DjiWaypointV2 struct for every waypoint -- file dji_waypoint_v2_type.h) and then you should be able to control the YAW with the remote control. but i am unsure of how to do that in the remote controller if that is offered as an option at every waypoint. sorry, i don't have my rc plus controller with me at present, so i can't check.

@atin42010 Thanks but we were trying to do this autonomously so wouldn't have access to the controller. After some  back and forth with DJI we have been told that this isn't possible without rewriting the whole control stack.

@Wachtel, I was afraid of that answer. i wonder if anyone else on the web has already written a custom flight control app that they can share with you. my requirements involve using the controller to a certain degree, so I am in the process of writing a custom app that can be started and stopped on a Raspberry Pi via the RC Plus controller. its going to be like a stripped down waypoint mission, going from point to point, but without all the things you can do at every waypoint. i am using a modified flight control sample app for the purposes. it might be worth exploring that option.
